# Function is undefined for no apparent reason

Tags: actionscript-3, function, keyboard

I have two event listeners calling two functions, the first `checkKeyDown` and then the second `checkKeyUp`.

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;


public class Code extends MovieClip {

    var charSpeed:int = 0;
    var velocity:int = 0;
    var gravity:Number = 1;
    var Jump:Boolean = false;


    public function startGame(){
         stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, checkKeyDown);
         stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, checkKeyUp);
     }

    public function Code() {
        // constructor code
    }

    function checkKeyDown(evt:KeyboardEvent){
        if (evt.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT){
            charSpeed -= 10;
        }
        if (evt.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT){
            charSpeed += 10;
        }
        if (evt.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN){
            if(!Jump){
                velocity -= 14;
                Jump = true;
            }
        }

    function checkKeyUp(e:KeyboardEvent){
        if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT){
            charSpeed = 0;
        }
        if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT){
            charSpeed = 0;
        }
    }
```

When I first typed the code, I did the `checkKeyDown` function first, and when I ran it, it worked fine (without the checkKeyUp event listener of course). After this, i added the event listener and checkKeyUp function to the code, but I got an error saying "1120: Access of undefined property checkKeyUp." I have no idea why this has come up, as the checkKeyDown function works fine. If I could get some help on why I am getting this error, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget a brace (char '}') at the end of checkKeyDown function.

Comment: @LouisCottier Make sure you mark Simsoft's answer as correct if it fixed the problem in the question.